# Iterating over non-zero elements of a Sparse Matrix in R using a function

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Following is an evaluation function which I am using as an input to a Genetic Algorithm:

```
evaluate <- function(string=c()) {
    z <- 0
    for (i in 1:56) {
        z=(z+cost[i,string[i]])
        for (j in 1:numadj[i]) {
            coi<-adj[i,j]
            d1<-string[i]
            d2<-string[coi]
            z=z+comrev[d1,d2]*wt[i,j]
        }
    }
    z
}
```

`Cost` is a `52x52` sparse matrix with a lot of zeros. Currently the code is actually iterating over all the elements. I want to make sure that the above function only loops through the non-zero values.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could consider using the `Matrix` library. By digging around in the object using `str`, you will see how it indexes non-zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually iterating over all the 52x52 (56x56?) entires in your
cost matrix, which you can see if you re-write your code like this:

```
evaluate <- function(string=c()) {
    z <- 0
    for (i in 1:56) 
        z = z + cost[i,string[i]]

    for (i in 1:56) 
        for (j in 1:numadj[i]) 
            z = z + comrev[string[i],
                           string[adj[i,j]]]*wt[i,j]
    return(z)
}
```

that said, you can initialize `z` a bit more efficiently, like so

```
evaluate <- function(string=c()) {

    z = sum(cost[cbind(1:56,match(string,colnames(cost))[1:56])])

    for (i in 1:56) 
        for (j in 1:numadj[i]) 
            z = z + comrev[string[i],
                           string[adj[i,j]]]*wt[i,j]
    return(z)
}
```

and I suspect the cost of identifying zeros would be similar to the cost of adding summing up the zero elements in this solution.